# Android: ToggleButton Listener

Tags: android

I have this code here

```
ToggleButton toggleAlarm = (ToggleButton) d.findViewById(R.id.toggle_alarm);
toggleAlarm.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if(isChecked)
        {
            Log.d("alarmCheck","ALARM SET TO TRUE");
            sched.setAlarm(true);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("alarmCheck","ALARM SET TO FALSE");
            sched.setAlarm(false);
        }
    }
});
```

I have to keep track if its ON or OFF. But when I logged something to logcat where it is on or off, it won't do a thing. I don't know, what is wrong, because on my other code same, syntax but it works I just copy paste it and change only the ToggleButton variable.

### **EDIT**

I have observed, with the help of cdr. Powell of course, that when you put this code block, the one that I have posted, inside another anonymous listener, say listener for a save button, the checkOnChangedListener is broken, it doesn't function well inside another anonymous listener, but the one thing that I don't understand is that, there is also a outer listener in my code, it is like a button to display a dialog box and inside that dialog box, there is an add button that opens another dialog box which has that toggle button and another button for save or add which closes that dialog and returns to the previous dialog which will then display the newly added record, so anyone of you have an idea why is it broken when i put it inside a listener for a save button but works fine in a outer listener.

Comment: I'd guess that `ToggleButton toggleAlarm = (ToggleButton) d.findViewById(R.id.toggle_alarm)` is broken since `onCheckedChanged()` is never being executed. Happens easily with c&p.

Comment: wat is c&p btw .. pardon my noobness kinda new in Mobile Dev.

Comment: copy'n'paste, sorry for my laziness.

Comment: ohhh i see, so i have to code it again?.. okie im gonna rewrite this one and see if it works, and if not, gonna try that guy's code below by Sir M Mohsin Naeem

Comment: I rather meant that your previous codebase, where you copied your code from, used another xml layout with differing id for the `ToggleButton`. Is that possible? But also true, had several builds where some changed classes weren't rebuild forcing me to clean the project which solved it.

Comment: yep it is on different layouts, and yes i have my own id unique with others..

Comment: btw i rewrote that code and also did  Sir M Mohsin Naeem suggestion.. both doesn't work.. hmmm im gonna try cleaning it

Comment: tried cleaning and dobulechecked my laayouts.. it has different ids

Comment: @Cdr.Powell kinda got what is going on with my code, refer to the edited post in the last part

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because - contrary its score - I could not find in it, where the sentences start. See the last paragraph. If you click "leave open", please fix the last paragraph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i have observed, with the help of cdr. powell of course, that when u put this code block, the one that i have posted, inside another anonymous listener, say listener for a save button, the checkOnChangedListener is broken, it doesn't function well inside another anonymous listener, but the one thing that i don't understand is that, there is also a outer listener in my code, its like a button to display a dialog box and inside that dialog box, there is an add button that opens another dialog box which has that toggle button and another button for save or add which closes that dialog and returns to the previous dialog which will then display the newly added record, so anyone of you have an idea why is it broken when i put it inside a listener for a save button but works fine in a outer listener.

Answer (score 20):

try this, May be the problem is with `import`

```
toggleAlarm.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if(isChecked)
    {
        Log.d("alarmCheck","ALARM SET TO TRUE");
        sched.setAlarm(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.d("alarmCheck","ALARM SET TO FALSE");
        sched.setAlarm(false);
    }

}
});
```

Comment: nope i doesn't work sir.. same as before logs nothings and does nothings as if that code block doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

Try `toggleAlarm.isChecked()` too see if the button is checked or not.

Answer (score 1):

In case toggleAlarm.isChecked() does not work for you you could always.

```
boolean _isChecked = false;
((ToggleButton) d.findViewById(R.id.toggle_alarm)).setOnClickListener(new OnOnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        _isChecked = !isChecked;            
        if(_isChecked()) {
            Log.d("alarmCheck","ALARM SET TO TRUE");
            sched.setAlarm(true);
        }
        else {
            Log.d("alarmCheck","ALARM SET TO FALSE");
            sched.setAlarm(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: make if(_isChecked())  -> if(_isChecked). Cause its not a methode in this case.