# how to get access to toggle buttons

Tags: android

How to have control over toggle buttons when my app first checks if in database it has **off** then my toggle button should be in off only if the user selects also.

```
 db.open();

 db.insertData(pos,val,"off","off");
```

it is my database on creating i am sending off.

```
beartoggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
/*  if(isChecked && check_port_1==1&& check_port_2==1){
         byte[] val={1};
       mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);
        //check_forservices(mBluetoothLeService.getSupportedGattServices());
    }

    else    if(!isChecked && check_port_1==1 && check_port_2==1){
         byte[] val={0};
           mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);
    }*/

    if(!isChecked ){
         byte[] val={0};
         //int val=0;
           mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,1);

          mBluetoothLeService.writeCharacteristic(val,2);}
}
});
}
```

this above code should have control over toggling using database data.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776423/android-togglebutton-listener)

Comment: if in database it is off means it should be off only in app if user toggle also.    like as settings option for bluetooth devices.